# How to select multiple plus Nested classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select multiple and nested , both classes in javascript. Its quite easy in jquery.
for eg -

HTML :

```
<div class="6a 6b">
    <a class="uiButton 1sm">
        <button class="uiButton 1sm">Select this<button>
    </a>
</div>
```

So i want to Select the "button" Using Multiple plus nested classes using javascript.
Working jquery :

```
var r = $('.6a.6b .uiButton.1sm .uiButtonText');
```

In javascript i tried :

```
var r = document.getElementByClassName('6a 6b uiButton 1sm uiButtonText');
```

But this dont Work.
Any ideas how should i go with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript use :

```
document.querySelectorAll(".6a.6b .uiButton.1sm .uiButtonText");
```

And the rest of the Jquery code inside parenthases Remains same.
Cheers :)

Comment: Works exactly the way i wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document.querySelectorAll( selectors )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
var r = document.querySelectorAll(".6a.6b .uiButton.1sm .uiButtonText");
```

[image]

Comment: Thnaxx this is what i was looking for :)

Comment: @A.Wolff check this too: [caniuse queryselector](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)